# Best infill for inter-layer adhesion

Tags: infill, print-strength

I'm fairly convinced that gyroid is the best infill for a lot of purposes, and use it regularly now, but both conceptually and anecdotally, it doesn't seem very good for reinforcing inter-layer adhesion. Each layer is essentially an overhang of the previous layer, and at one step in each period there's even a bridge, meaning that the layers do not get pressed tightly together during printing.

Is there any data on how different infill patterns perform against tension perpendicular to the Z-axis, or angular around the Z-axis, which generally results in layers separating? I would guess "2D" infill patterns provide the best strength here, and I could experiment with it myself, but I'd like to know if it's already been tested.

Comment: All tests that I've seen test the shear stress of the infill. Loading parts in Z direction means that you would test the inter-layer strength, which is prone to failure as in effect in between every Z layer you have a crack initiation point.

Comment: @0scar: For what it's worth, I just had amazing results with PETG and triangles infill here: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/10035/11157

Comment: I think I need to get myself a low-range torque wrench and do some measurements...

Comment: Reminder to self or others for something to test: increasing `infill_line_width` to something like double nozzle size to see if it gets better layer adhesion with 3d infills. If this makes gyroid comparably strong, it would be a small net material cost vs 2d infills (if any cost at all) and a big win for print time.